# Regex find exactly six quotation marks anywhere in a line

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to find a regex that will return true if there are exactly 6 double quotes(") in a line.

I have tried this:

```
["]{6}
```

but that only seems to return 6 double quotes if they are right next to each other.

```
1. """""" = true
2. "ashsjg"sgshs"skjgsk"skhsgh"sjg" = false
```

Is there a way to check for 6 quotes anywhere in the line so that 2. becomes true?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to match non-quotes between the quotes. And you have to anchor the regexp so it won't allow quotes before/after the match.

```
^(?:[^"]*"){6}[^"]*$
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to know whether there are 6 double quote in a string, you can try this:

```py
import re
re_quote = re.compile('"')
def six_double_quote(line):
    if len(re.findall(re_quote,line))==6:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

but I think that just use `count` of string is more simple:

```py
def six_double_quote(line):
    if line.count('"')==6:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```